# Notation for the placement of two matrices at their corners

Tags: linear-algebra, notation

I’ve looked and looked and just cannot find the name of this thing online. It’s the operation between two matrices with a notation that is a circle with a cross in the middle. It means “A —operation— B equals”:$$=\begin{bmatrix}A&0\\0&B\end{bmatrix}\\$$ And the zeroes denote zero rectangular matrices of a suitable size. Many thanks for clearing up the failure of my memory!

Answer from the comments: it was the direct sum operation, denoted by $\oplus$. I edited the question title too so that someone in need may be more likely to stumble across it.

Comment: The notation you're describing kinda sounds like $A \otimes B$ but that's not how I would describe that operation, probably more like $A \oplus B$. This is the direct sum.

Comment: It is exactly the $\oplus$ operation! @OsamaGhani what’s its name, thank you!

Comment: https://mathworld.wolfram.com/MatrixDirectSum.html

Comment: @JMoravitz perfect! Can’t believe I forgot

Comment: For what its worth, there are many times in exercises and the like where a new operation is introduced which for all intents and purposes is specific to that problem and need not be named at the time.  Some of the time, these special operations are being introduced just to plant the seed of familiarity in the student's head but might not reappear again until several chapters or even courses later.  You might not always find out that these toy operations are actually used anywhere further than the problem's context however, so it doesn't always help to try to find the name.